# 403 Forbidden - Spring security with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have my spring boot application and I'm trying to add spring security but when I do a request through postman I keep getting a 403 Forbbiden,
Online I found I shoud add: ".csrf().disable()" to my configure but it didn't work
(Everithing works if I put the method with path: "person/**" in the permitAll())

here my code:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document("User")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Set<UserRole> roles;
}

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;
  @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);}

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.info("HttpSecurity: {}",http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/user/saveUser").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/person/**").hasAnyRole()
                .and().csrf().disable().cors().disable();}
}

public class UserService implements UserDetailsService{
    private final UserRepository userRepo;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        log.info("mail request: {}",email);
        Optional<User> opt = userRepo.findUserByEmail(email);
        log.info("Find user: {}", opt);
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User springUser=null;

        if(opt.isEmpty()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with email: " +email +" not found");
        }else {
            User user =opt.get();
            Set<UserRole> roles = user.getRoles();
            Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
            for(UserRole role:roles) {
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
            }
            springUser = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                    email,
                    user.getPassword(),
                    grantedAuthorities );

        }
        return springUser;
    }
```

My controller for User:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("user")
public class UserController {
    private final UserService userService;
    @PostMapping("/saveUser")
    public ResponseEntity<String> saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        log.info("Registering User: {}", user);
        userService.saveUser(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("registered User");
    }
}
```

My person controller: (method whereI get 403)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("person")
public class PersonController {
@Autowired
PersonService personService;
@GetMapping("/getAll")
public ResponseEntity<List> getAll() throws IOException {
return ResponseEntity.ok(PersonService.findAll());
}

This is first time I use spring security, I followed a tutorial online but I realy can't figure out why evetime I put my request in security it still get 403 Forbidden

Comment: Looks like you're missing a controller

Comment: @Sam I added now

Comment: Dis you red about CSRF and CORS before disabling it ?

Comment: @Zorglube I read if I m going to use on postman I should disable CSRF

Comment: No, if you add what CSRF check need in the request you emit from Postman, you don't need to disable it.

Comment: @Zorglube I took off but I still getting 403 Forbidden

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Glossary/CSRF

Comment: A shot in the dark: Add a slash here: ` @RequestMapping("/user")`

Comment: I would suggest you read the actual spring security documentation and not outdated tutorials

Comment: I do not understand what are you trying to achieve by 

 .antMatchers( "/user/saveUser").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/person/**").hasAnyRole()

usually it is only the SIGN_UP endpoint and login endpoints etc that we want to permit. Anyways my first thought would be either to remove "hasAnyRole". If eveything works it means it is the role configuration that needs to be done.

Comment: @NullishByte it depend if you want to secure a `Method` or an end-point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add `@Configuration` and `@EnableWebSecurity` annotations to your `SecurityConfig` class, because spring-security can't see your security configuration without them.

See reference documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html

Mind also, that `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` was [deprecated](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) since 5.7.0-M2, so you might consider creating a bean of type `SecurityFilterChain` to configure security in your app if you use later versions of spring-security.